# Actionscript 2, Flash 8 and Amazon S3. Is there an AS2.0 API?

Tags: flash, authentication, actionscript-2, amazon-s3

I am developing an application that loads images and video into a Flash player (currently using Flash 8 to develop so this is AS2.0). We are going to host the files on Amazon S3 servers. Can anyone point out the best way to go about loading the files into Flash Player from Amazon S3. I have been using MovieClipLoader to load images from our development server using loadMovie("http://domain/folder/file") and progressive video is loaded in a similar way. I want to be able to load from S3 like I did from our development server. Do I need to go through the signature and authentication process when loading each item into Flash from S3? I dont fully understand how I would generate signature etc in Flash. Can I use the PHP S3 class to do this and send the signature etc as a variable to Flash at the start and use the same signature for loading all images / video?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assets hosted on Amazon S3 are available without any authentication, assuming ACL settings allow read access. So you should not need to supply a signature or authentication to simply download stuff. For example here is an image file I have on S3 that's accessible via a simple url:

<strike>[gromit.jpg](http://s3.amazonaws.com/Evernden/gromit.jpg)</strike> (Dead Link)

Do you have a requirement that your assets be protected from viewing by anyone w/o credentials?

Comment: Hi, yes I think so - we really need to prevent anyone from being able to viewing the files, so only people using our web application shouel be able to access files on S3.

many thanks for your help!